# How to set SameSite value to None or Undefined for OWIN OpenIdConnect.Nonce cookie on .NET 4.7.2

Tags: asp.net, cookies, owin, identityserver4, samesite

I'm running an ASP.NET MVC (4.7.2) web application. I authenticate externally with an Identity Server 4 instance with the Hybrid flow.

When testing the new "missing SameSite defaults to LAX" feature of Firefox, he doesn't sent the LAX OpenIdConnect.Nonce cookie back to my MVC web application:

Image 1: all cookies have Lax

[image: All cookies have Lax]

Image 2: No cookies provided at POST to **signin-oidc**

[image: Missing nonce cookie in the callback from Identity Server]

I get the error:

> OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null,
>   OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The
>   nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set
>   OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a
>   'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.

I tried a few things to enfore all cookies to have at least a None or Unspecified setting, but this OpenIdConnect.Nonce cookie keeps sticking at LAX.

```
app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
    CookieSameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
    CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager())
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = configDetails.IdentityProviderUrl,
    AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
    ClientId = configDetails.ClientId,
    Scope = configDetails.Scope,
    ResponseType = "id_token code",
    RedirectUri = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(configDetails.RedirectUri) ? configDetails.RedirectUri : "~/",
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
    UseTokenLifetime = false,
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        AuthorizationCodeReceived = AuthorizationCodeReceived,
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
        {
            if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType != Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout) return Task.FromResult(0);

            var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");
            if (idTokenHint != null)
            {
                n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    },
    CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager()),
});
```

In my web.config I've added:

```
<system.web>
  <httpCookies sameSite="None" requireSSL="true" />
</system.web>
```

I'm using the SameSiteCookieManager from [Microsoft MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/owin-samesite).

I hope someone can help me setting this OpenIdConnect.Nonce cookie to None or Unspecified.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: MS provided a runtime patch that changes the SameSite behaviour in ASP.Net. Have you applied this prior to testing?

Comment: @mackie Thanks for your reply. We host on Azure, running the EU-West region. According to this article (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/app-service-samesite-cookie-update/) the patch should be applied on Azure in January. But, we did not check the Patch versions. And offcourse, the instance we are working on does not have this patch (86.0.7.90 on Azure, required is 86.0.7.148). So that might be it!

Comment: @JonHendrix I essentially have the exact same setup and I see your ASPNET_SessionID. I'm successfully getting that cookie to be Strict: None; Secure. When I visit site, a Set-Cookie is issued for it. but when my MVC page performs the redirect (keycloak in this case), the ASP.Net_SessionID is not subsequently set in the request to there and gets lost - therefore when i finish auth with keycloak and return to the original url - i no longer have that cookie. How did you get yours to stick?

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the SameSite issue by attaching to RedirectToIdentityProvider and manually setting it from there. Something like this:

```
RedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
{
    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
    {
        var nonceKey = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.AllKeys.Where(x => x.Contains("nonce")).FirstOrDefault();
        if (nonceKey != null)
        {
            var nonce = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Get(nonceKey);
            nonce.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this approach however the HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies has 0 cookies when i debug it (despite the fact that I eventually see them in the browser). Im trying to set the Secure flag on it as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same setup as you with IdSvr4 and asp.net 4.7.2 for the sameSite cookie changes. Mine seems to be working now. I used that cookie manager which seemed to do the trick. I didn't do the system.web httpCookie element though. See here to see if my post on this helps.

[SO post on framework 4.7.2 and sameSite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58251873/what-is-the-right-way-to-reference-system-net-http-when-targeting-net-4-7-2/63305198#63305198)